# WiFi package for flutter for an app to connect to home or public Wi-Fi

Tags: flutter, dart, android-wifi

I am looking for a wifi package in flutter which allow me to connect to home or public wifi, most of the wifi package in flutter have been depreceated, I have tried wifi_iot package but it doesn't seem to be working. When I run the package, the interface run but when I click anything it does not connect or reconnect the wifi.Can I have some tips on using the package, from the experience users here.[WiFi_iot package link](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_iot/example)

Comment: Can you help by explaining the task you want to accomplish . The package you linked looks like it works under certain constraints. Are you sure the device you are using meets the criteria for the package?

Comment: @VipinKumarKashyap hi thanks for responding i need to create a mobile app that can connect to any public wifi or  tp link wireless router , then these tp link router will have VPN enabled on it so that I can browse through safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for provisioning with wifi this repo can help you
[Github Repo](https://github.com/MurtuzaSrashtaSoft/esp_provisioning?ref=flutterawesome.com)

```
 EspProv prov = EspProv(
    transport: TransportBLE(ble_peripheral), security: Security1(pop: pop));
 var success = await prov.establishSession();
 await prov.sendWifiConfig(ssid: event.ssid, password: event.password);
 await prov.applyWifiConfig();
```

Comment: thank you for responding, if you have any video to guide me through clearly through these package would be better, however I thank you for helping me out

Comment: repo contains one .gif which can help you

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicloudvn/esp_provisioning/master/img.gif