# How to connect to wifi in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an application which requires to connect to wifi. I have tried

1. wifi_connect,
2. wifi_connector,
3. android_flutter_wifi etc. packages. Either they are outdated (app doesn't build if I add them in pub dev) or doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi package for flutter for an app to connect to home or public Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495114/wifi-package-for-flutter-for-an-app-to-connect-to-home-or-public-wi-fi)

Comment: @Kalyan isn't that for ESP32 devices?

Comment: Yes it is. I overlooked it. Take a look at `wifi_iot` package instead.